# Rails 7 session_id cookie different from sessions table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using active_record_store for sessions:
session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

I have code for reading/parsing the session data for logging purposes.
When the user logs into the ui, I get a new record in the sessions table, with a session_id like:

```
2::cbd180f1b721cc89d70e417661cf43c83f34d1c967a76daf14ca77db094a423a
```

But in my controller, when I look at cookies['_session_id'], I get:

```
eac9bd2420e0f5dbdfc22654df3b78dc
```

What is causing the discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this, I found the answer in the rack gem, file lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb.
The code refers to a public session id, which is the one in the cookie.
The private session id is:

```
"2::#{Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(public_session_id)}"
```